# Display David Rumsey' Georeferencer tiles in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying tu use David Rumsey' [Georeferencer tiles](https://davidrumsey.georeferencer.com/maps/467360267090/)  in R leaflet package without success (Only the OSM basemap is displayed).
[image]
According to the [package vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/basemaps.html) I tried :

```
   library(leaflet)
            # XYZ direct link                
            leaflet() %>%
              setView(0.65, 0, zoom = 5) %>%
              addTiles() %>% 
              addTiles("https://maps.georeferencer.com/georeferences/700526190853/2017-12-30T11:48:27.589686Z/map.json?key=D7AwmpRP1H6pUic6DIK3")
```

and

```
 library(leaflet)
            # WMS tiles
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% setView(0.65, 0, zoom = 5) %>%
      addWMSTiles(
        "https://maps.georeferencer.com/georeferences/700526190853/2017-12-30T11:48:27.589686Z/wmts?key=D7AwmpRP1H6pUic6DIK3&SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities",
    layers = "1", # I assume
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = FALSE),
    attribution = "")
```

Notes :
- The access at the map links need free registration.
- I used the 2.1 package release.
- The vignette's addWMSTiles example is working on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using the `addLayersControl` function that can allow me to choose the layer to display.

```
       library(leaflet)
      m <- leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels, group = "DarkMatter") %>%
      addTiles("https://maps.georeferencer.com/georeferences/700526190853/2017-12-30T11:48:27.589686Z/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=D7AwmpRP1H6pUic6DIK3", group ="H") %>% 
        addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("DarkMatter", "H"), position ="topleft")
      m
```